# python lxml scraping giving blank result

Tags: python, lxml

I have tried this but getting blank result

```
import requests

from lxml import html

response=requests.get('http://www.convertit.com/Go/ConvertIt/Currency/Convert_All_Output.ASP?FCu=USD')

tree = html.fromstring(response.text)

print (tree.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr[41]/td[1]/text()'))
```

Comment: used same code with selenium its working but lxml it is showing blank result.

Comment: Because there is no any tbody in the table. Look the document source

Comment: Selenium has a browser fixing your html/xml behind the scenes. You really probably want [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) unless it's *actually* guarenteed to be an xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Lol4t0 said in a comment, there is no `tbody` in the source. If you change your last line to read

```
print (tree.xpath('//div/table/tr[41]/td[1]/text()'))
```

you'll get the result of `['62.525']`.